# Buttons overlay in xs viewport because not auto resize

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one line (div tag with class is `col-xs-6`) with 2 columns of the same width. Inside each column, there is one auto-resizing button with the max width is 150px depends on the length of the text inside. SO I input the very long text inside the buttons so they got the same max width, that is 150px. Then I auto resize the window to xs viewport, until one size (I think the width of the window is smaller than 300px plus padding) then the buttons overlay on each other.

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 34px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ff7900;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff7900;
}

.nf-filler-control input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.nf-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div style="background:green;" class="col-xs-6">
    <div>
      <div class=" nf-filler-control nf-filler-highlightonvalidationerror nf-button">
        <input type="submit" value="As he crossed tosssss sxcffffxxx" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="background:red;" class="nf-col col-xs-6">
    <div>
      <div class=" nf-filler-control nf-filler-highlightonvalidationerror nf-button">
        <input type="submit" value="As he crossed tosssss sxcffffxxx" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </d
```

The problem is: Currently, the div tag auto resize but the buttons keep the same width (they don't auto resize along with the parent div tag). So they overflow outside parent div tags and overlay on each other.

What I expect here is:

- Solution 1: when I auto resize the window, the div tag auto resize but the buttons still keep the same width so to one point, there is no enough space for both so it should break into 2 lines (one button on each line)
- Solution 2: when I auto resize the window, the div tag auto resize then the button auto resize (they should always be inside the div tag, not overflow)

Below is my code in fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/toy56gyf/2/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it won't re-size is because they have a static width and height, due to the fact that you used pixels as the format. Change everything you have with px to vw and vh. Also you should add `top: 0px; left: 0px; position absolute;` to the css and then move it around with `Transform: translate(0-100vw, 0-100 vh);`

This will ensure that it does not move around, and that it re-size properly :-)